# How I could replicate this bumpy texture?

Tags: texturing

I was curious if anyone had any ideas on how I could replicate this texture? If I start playing around with texture displacements, but it always breaks the mesh.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hello Oliver :). Please mark one of the answers as accepted if it solved you problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you'd rather not spend the poly-budget until render-time, you could do it with a Cycles (only) displacement shader. The features seem to be following the topology, so you could <kbd>U</kbd> UV unwrap your object with the 'Reset' option. That will make all the quads occupy the whole 0-1 UV space.

For render-time displacement to work,at the time of writing, Cycles has to be set to 'Experimental', and the material has to be set to 'Displacement', or 'Displacement and Bump' in its *Settings* panel.

The object has to be subdivided sufficiently to resolve the displacement detail. However, Cycles can decide how much render-time subdivision is needed, on a per-pixel basis, by giving the object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, and checking 'Adaptive'.

Then you can use this sort of shader-tree:

[image]

To get this sort of result:

[image]

The 'Subtract' and 'Multiply' nodes could be a vector 'Mapping' node, if you prefer, and the 'Vector Curves' could be a 'Color Ramp' node, if you'd find it easier to use.

EDIT: Thanks to commentary by @Chris, about problems he encountered with this tree, I think it would actually be easier to use RGB Curves than Vector Curves.. the 'C' combined adjustment becomes available.. it behaves better. Here's his .blend, given the easier set-up:

[image]

Comment: Edit: I was asking you to share your file but I rebuilt it from scratch, powerful method...

Comment: Oops! Maybe I should have shared.. I would have to remake it, it was just a quickie. I'll wait to see whether @Oliver goes this way, and needs more help.

Comment: Hello mr. Betts :). Great one. Could you please edit in that it needs *Displacement* enabled in Material settings, and currently only works in Cycles? We have some confused users... Thanks :).

Comment: @JachymMichal Wilko!

Comment: I tried to replicate it but I think I have not understood something ... is it possible to have an illustrated procedure step by step?

Comment: @matibuc, sorry for late reply.. maybe you could share a little example that's going wrong on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ? Then I could see what I was missing, in the answer.

Comment: Hi @RobinBetts , thank for the reply. I replicated the same shader that i see here above, i assigned it to the object but nothing happened. I unwrapped the object but i don't know what does it mean uv unwrap with the "reset" option.

Comment: Hi, @matibuc.. 'Reset' is the last of the options in the (U) unwrap menu, visible in Edit mode, preferably in the UV editing workspace. .. I _think_ I've mentioned everything else: Cycles, Experimental, the Material 'Settings' panel, pref. a _Subdivision Surface_ modifier, set to 'Adaptive'. Try it on a simple plane, to kick off with. Go ahead and share if you're still stuck.

Comment: Dear Master Betts, i tried to reproduce your amazing tutorial, but i am too silly :( I got spikey instead of round "hills". What am i doing wrong?  here is my blend file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=xElK35xB" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/xElK35xB/) . Of course if anybody else know my mistake, feel free to help me out ;) i just get this: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgUnu.png

Comment: @Chris 'Haro, Glasshoppa!' (hmm.. enough of that :D) Partly your problem, (subdividing geometry _after_ resetting the UV, so quads are _not_ filling UV 0-1). Partly mine. Looking back, I think it's more intuitive to use RGB Curves, where you can control everything through the 'C' combined channel. Without worrying about how X,Y, and Z all contributing to the vector->value cast if you use Vector Curves. Do I have permission to link your file, corrected, in this answer?

Comment: Yes of course and thank you!!

Comment: @Chris Done. Thanks.

Comment: ok, for those who also tried to rebuild this great solution and struggled - one more important info: the vector curves have to be the same on x,y,z as Robin showed us, not just for. x as the image might say...unfortunately not everybody is a mathematics genius like Robin is ;)

Answer (score 20):

You can try it with the **Tissue** addon:

- Activate the Tissue addon. Create your module (make sure the vertices that are on the perpendicular borders can fit):

[image]

- Create your target object (here a sphere), keep in mind that the Tissue addon will use the faces of the target object to duplicate the module:

[image]

- Open the *N* panel > *Edit > Tissue Tools*. Select the module object, shift select the target object, click *Tessellate*, keep the default settings, press *OK*:

[image]

- It has created a new object. Go in *Edit* mode and *Merge Vertices by Distance*. Right click and *Shade Smooth*. Give it a *Smooth* modifier and a *Subdivision Surface* modifier. Increase the *Factor* value of the *Smooth* modifier until the new object has a smooth sphere shape, then apply this modifier only:

[image]