# Pack instances of object on surface of mesh

Tags: mesh, particles, force-fields, packing

I'm trying to achieve something like this (https://www.instagram.com/p/B9E5hH-oKi8/) with blender.

Is there any way I can achieve something similar? Maybe by using a force field and a particle system?
I've been fiddling around with hair partlce systems but I couldn't figure out a way to not have instances overlapping, and the tests I've been doing with force fields seem not to nail it either. THe best thing I could achieve was particles sticking to the closest section of the target object, but not flowing evenly like in the shown video.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm not sure it exists in Blender but you can use the Tissue addon as explained here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194667/how-i-could-replicate-this-bumpy-texture/194677#194677 ... as Tesselat uses the faces of your object, make sure that your quads are even, if they are not, duplicate your object and Remesh with the Voxel method

Comment: I need the faces to be all the same size in order to achieve something like in the video, and both tesselate+voxel and dual meshes don't really nail it. Moreover I'm aiming at something that doesn't destructively predetermine the faces' size

Comment: yes but you could duplicate your object, remesh the duplication and make it invisible, it's just a trick in case you don't find the solution  ;)   it would be better to have an option that prevents particle overlapping and allows a perfect even emission but I'm not sure it exists yet