# bubbles on sphere

Tags: node-editor

i try to implement the solution of Robin Betts "bubbles":
[How I could replicate this bumpy texture?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194667/how-i-could-replicate-this-bumpy-texture/194677#194677)

but no "bubbles" appear....can anybody help me, what am i doing wrong?

here is my blend file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/onp7jim8bvi3491/bubbles_on_surface_with_nodes.blend?dl=0

Comment: Hello :). Keep in mind you need to enable Displacement in material settings, and it only works in Cycles. *Options > Displacement > Displacement*.

Comment: thank you! works now

Comment: Thanks to @Jachym, answer now updated.. sorry it wasn't clearer in the original.

Comment: No problem - i am just a total beginner