# Making fluffy tail

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects

I am currently working on a Pokemon model. Got almost all the model done but I have problems making the tail.

[image]

[image]

I want the tail based on the top image like a giant ball with fluff around like a fur ball. I found that maybe the bottom images could be a great reference to go with. Any idea on how I can reach this model? Maybe any modifier or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do what you show on your second picture you could use the ***Tissue*** addon, see [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194667/how-i-could-replicate-this-bumpy-texture/194677#194677).

To do something more organic like what you show on your first picture you could use ***Metaballs*** (to increase their resolution, go into the *Properties panel > Object Data > Metaball >* and lower down the *Resolution* value):

[image]

When you're glad, go in the header menu > *Object > Convert To > Mesh*:

[image]

Then to reduce the amount of polygons, go into the *Properties panel > Object Data > Remesh*, and choose for example the *Quads* mode with the number of faces you want:

[image]

Now you have your tail object:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That worked with the desired result.